# How can I click on the next button programmatically using console in gmail to view older mails?

Tags: javascript

I want to click on the next button in gmail using console so that I can vie wmy  older mails. Is it possible?

I have found the id of the button they are using but this doesn't seem to do anything

```
document.getElementById(":hc").click();
```

Comment: a=document.getElementById("idofbutton").click and than simply do a();

Comment: @Jonasw I have done that but it didn't seem to work

Comment: What does document.getElementById(":hc") return?

Comment: it returned undefined

Comment: Well check the id...

Comment: i have checked it many times ,the following code is written when i inspect the element

Comment: <div id=":hc" class="T-I J-J5-Ji amD T-I-awG T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-Gs L3" role="button" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Older" aria-label="Older" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">…</div>

Comment: Ok actually im confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ids seems to be dynamic but yes to see older mails try below given code:-

```
  function clickNext(id) {
        var cl = document.getElementById(id);
        triggerMouseEvent(cl, "mousedown");

        triggerMouseEvent(cl, "mouseup");
    }
```

and trigger mouse event function code:-

```
function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

In clickNext function pass the id of button in my case below code is working fine and I am able to see older mails in gmail:-

```
clickNext(":jh");
```